# Why do I get that SingularValueDecomposition cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java

I added Jama to buildpath, imported the right class yet eclipse gives me this error.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Ill post a better screenshot in a minute.

Comment: You're missing a name of the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to state an identifier after

```
SingularValueDecomposition
```

like

```
SingularValueDecomposition myValueDecomp = An.svd();
```

etter paste your code then. 
I just downloaded Jama and created a simple code snippet with your getSingularVectors method in NetBeans and Eclipse Kepler and it works for me.
my code:

```
private ArrayList<Vector<Double>> getSingularVectors(Matrix an, int i){
    ArrayList<Vector<Double>> list = new ArrayList<Vector<Double>>(i);
    SingularValueDecomposition svd = an.svd();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i played with it after it gave me that error. there's a variable name there, sorry for the confusion

Comment: So is this the correct answer, or not? Why did you accept it?